# lightning:listView inside vertical lightning:tabset gets clipped

Tags: lightninglistview, lightning-tabset

When using vertical tabset, list views are getting clipped if there's many fields on a view. Somehow on a regular tabset it works displays horizontal scroll, but on vertical it clips off action buttons and the like. Resizing fields works, but not a starter for us.

See code and screenshot below

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <lightning:tabset variant="vertical">
        <lightning:tab label="Home" iconName="utility:home">
            <lightning:listView
                    objectApiName="Account"
                    listName="MyNS__AllAccounts"
                    showActionBar="true"/>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

[[image]
[[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to fix it you can fix it by setting this in css though i am not sure why doesn't it worked by default

```
.THIS .slds-vertical-tabs__content{
        overflow:auto;
    }
```